# Resistance between data/Addr pins and GND ranges from 1k to 1M, is this normal?

Tags: resistance, dsp, signal-integrity

After soldering a 132-pin surface mount DSP, I checked if there are short circuits or not using "GreenLee DM-110" multimeter. I found that the resistance between data or address pins and GND ranges from ~1K Ohm to 1M Ohm.

I know that I should measure an open circuit or several (hundreds!) mega ohms. Why is the resistance too low? Can this cause any danger to DSP operation?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds plausible. You have to remember that when your IC is not powered, you may be measuring the resistance of its input protection diodes (which prevent the input pins exceeding the power supply) rather than the input circuitry itself.

So you cannot conclude from these measurements that there is any fault. However, if you are not using ESD-safe practices there is a risk of damaging the IC from the measurement process itself.

Now resistance above 10 megohms, or below 1 ohm, would be more worrying; they might indicate an open circuit or short circuit from bad soldering.

Comment: Ok if this is the resistance of an internal circuit, why is it different between pins of the same function (data/Addr)? Can soldering flux residues between pins cause these differences?

Comment: Difficult to say. Remember you are partially powering the chip this way. Different transistors may start to turn on at slightly different voltages making wildly different impedances, though they all appear to work the same when the supply voltage is correct. Flux is HIGHLY unlikely to be conductive enough to affect it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to verify the solder connections of the DSP chip alone, without other components added to the board, you should be looking for a diode between each pin and ground and between each pin and a power supply. For input pins this will be the ESD protection diodes and for output pins you will see the drain-to-body diodes of the output transistors. The manufacturer knows the expected forward voltage drop at some specified current (probably in the milliampere range) for each pin but you can probably get a good idea just by looking at a number of pins. On the other hand, sometimes there are more exotic ESD protection circuits used for I/O pins that are designed to tolerate input voltages higher than the logic supply voltage, and in those cases you may not see a simple diode structure between the pin and the supply voltage.

Before checking the input/output pins, make sure that there is a low resistance between all of the pins that are connected to ground and all of the pins connected to the supply voltage.

Comment: Yes there is a low resistance between supplies and between grounds. Kindly check my comment on Brian's answer.

Comment: First of all, keep in mind that this is not just a resistive circuit...you are also measuring the voltage of a very non-linear diode. Trying to measure the "resistance" will never give good results. As to your question above, of course the resistances will be different. How different are they? How exactly are you measuring them?